# Logitech H800 bluetooth headset with Dell XPS1330

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, dell-xps

When I use my H800 bluetooth headset I can get everything working except of Stereo audio. I have tried to re-install the driver, but I fail. Obviously I cannot find the proper driver, I have tried Broadcom latest ([SetupBtwDownloadSE](http://www.broadcom.com/support/license.php?file=SetupBtwDownloadSE.exe).exe), but it won't install (says "Cannot upgrade your software, contact manufacturer")

All H800 software is installed. I have problems to find the appropriate Win 7 (32) bluetooth driver on Dell's site (actually I do not see which driver would be applicable, there's no term bluetooth).

OS: Windows 7, 32bit

[image: BT Stereo Audio a]
[image: BT Stereo Audio b]

Comment: Did you try contacting the manufacturer?

Comment: For me this means "Go and check the dell web site", or what else should I do?

Comment: Luckily I found a driver that works, thanks for your input. I had to reinstall it twice for some reasons, however, issue is gone now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually I found a driver that is working, but is not on the XPS 1330 page.

```
Bluetooth Driver
Description: Dell Wireless 355 Bluetooth 2.0 + EDR Module
Release: 01/26/2007, 6.0.1.3100, A00
Size: 44.00 MB
Download: R140135
Source: Dell
```

**With the term "R140135" you can search and find it on the Dell Site.**

IMHO, this (http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php) would be the logical update of the driver, but does not work in my Win7 environment.

Comment: Nice find. Can you share the driver you found for future visitors?

Comment: Updated, use the R140135 term to locate it on the Dell site, better as a link which will not work after a while.